# What are the conditions for regex (|) pipe operator short circuiting to work?

Tags: regex

The pipe/or (`|`) operator in regex is supposed to short circuit. However, in the examples below, the matches do not seem to be consistent. Specifically, why does the short circuiting work in the first example and not the second one?

Short circuiting works in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/0Rj4ml/1):

```
.*#|^#.*
```

matches only `#` in `#B` (the left pattern only even though the right one should match `#B`)

Short circuiting does not seem to work in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/lg20RK/1):

```
#.*|.*#$
```

matches the entire `A#` in `A#` (even though the left pattern should only match `#` at the end and break)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe operator short-circuits, but the matcher will try to match as early in the string as possible. In your second example, the second pattern matches because it can match the first character in the string, whereas the first pattern cannot. This **takes precedence** over the short-circuiting behavior of the `|` operator.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It perfectly explains these matches. Can you share your reference on precedence taking over the short-circuiting behavior with the pipe operator?

Comment: I don't have a reference; it's mainly from experience working with regular expressions.

Comment: I found a secondary reference at https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html , where it describes the regex as "eager". As it walks through each character of the string, it attempts to match each alternative to the characters so far. By the time it gets to the second character '#', the first alternative has already been eliminated. As soon as the second alternative is satisified (at '$'), the regex has succeeded, so it eagerly reports the match. It never takes the opportunity to backtrack and test a new match starting with the second character.